# State is not getting updated in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the finalShapes state from initialShapes state and I am having a problem that finalShapes is not getting updated. I am making some changes in initalShapes state and then storing that manipulated data in finalShapes.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong

```
this.state.initialShapes.map (sh => {
   var data = {};
   data.name = sh.name;
   data.x1 = sh.x;
   data.y1 = sh.y;
   data.x2 = sh.x + sh.width;
   data.y2 = sh.y + sh.height;
   this.setState ({finalShapes : [...this.state.finalShapes, data]});
});
```

Comment: this is not the way you work with `setState` are you trying to update the state on each iteration?

Comment: You shouldn't be setting state on an iteration, but rather creating an object copy of the original state, acting on that copy to create your new state, and finally use one setState to set your final state to your edited copy

Comment: yes and what am i actually doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest to use the callback form of the setState if you want to access the previous state, like `this.setState(prevState => { ... })`.

Comment: ok but why we cannot do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not update the state in a loop because it does not immediately update the state. It means that the next iteration of the loop will not see updated `state`.

[ReactDocs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall.

You can copy your `inistialShapes` and update the state once

```
var updatedShapes = this.state.initialShapes.map (sh => {
  var data = {};
  data.name = sh.name;
  data.x1 = sh.x;
  data.y1 = sh.y;
  data.x2 = sh.x + sh.width;
  data.y2 = sh.y + sh.height;

  return data;
});

this.setState ({finalShapes : updatedShapes });
```